# Display page content using multiple templates - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to have a page like: *www.site.com/page/*

and show different templated versions using, say:

*www.site.com/page/?template=default*

*www.site.com/page/?template=archive*

...?

So it retrieves the same page content but displays it differently.

Is this possible with WordPress? Is it standard or would need some tomhackery to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you look this over and see if it helps either solve the problem, or help you expand on the question? [Using different page templates with the same page content](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-different-page-templates-with-the-same-page-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 'master' template and assign it to your page. The master template doesn't contain any layout information—just a set of conditional include statements that selects the 'real' template based on the GET variable. The master template might look something like this:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET["template"]) {
    case "foo":
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/foo.php");
        break;
    case "bar":
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/bar.php");
        break;
    case "baz":
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/baz.php");
        break;
    default:
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/default_template.php");
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Gabe. Yep, that's my thinking too. I've done it before that way, but just in case I was being a bit silly doing it this way. Thanks for the reassurance :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting this—I've removed my initial wrong answer and spelled out the correct version better.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a similar question a moment ago.

[Manually set template using PHP in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723764/manually-set-template-using-php-in-wordpress)

The answer above should work, but the use of TEMPLATEPATH, I think is not ideal, it also seems to not take advantage of what WordPress is already doing to select a template.

```
function filter_page_template($template){

        /* Lets see if 'template is set' */
        if( isset($_GET['template']) ) {

            /* If so, lets try to find the custom template passed as in the query string. */
            $custom_template = locate_template( $_GET['template'] . '.php');

            /* If the custom template was not found, keep the original template. */
            $template = ( !empty($custom_template) ) ?  $custom_template : $template;
        }

        return $template;
}
add_filter('page_template', 'filter_page_template');
```

Doing it this way, you don't need to add a new line for every template you want to be able to specify. Also, you take advantage of the existing template hierarchy, and account for the possibility that a non-existant template was entered.

I would point out that you should do some validation against the $_GET['template'] value before using it, but also that you might want to keep a running list to check against, so that they cant simply use any old template.