# Dynamically change Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

How can I set an a tag to dynamically change the theme currently being displayed by wordpress?

I understand the switch function as described in a similar question here: [Display page content using multiple templates - WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620898/display-page-content-using-multiple-templates-wordpress) , but I don't know how to implement the change. Should the switch be added to index.php inside a theme, or inside the theme folder? Does my link point to the index.php file?

I would like to do this without a plugin if possible.

An example of a site which does this already: www.envye.com/wordpress/

Thank you!

Comment: WordPress Template <> WordPress Theme

Comment: What you want to use is a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Comment: Ssergei: I don't want a page template - I want a template to display across the entire site when clicked. No matter what page/post/sidebar a visitor is on, they can change the template.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in function.php

```
function fxn_change_theme($theme) {

  if( $condition == true )
    $theme = 'twentytwelve';
  else
    $theme = 'twentyteleven';

  return $theme;
}

add_filter('template', 'fxn_change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'fxn_change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'fxn_change_theme');
```

Comment: Pokhrel: 

What would the $condition be? How can I tell the function that it is time to change template based on a click?

Comment: Here are some easy steps.

1. you can pass a value of theme on click, 
2. reload the page 
3. get the value in a variable.
4. pass the variable in the above condition.

Comment: @slash are the last two filters hooking into existing options or are those custom made? I'm specifically referring to 'option-template' and 'option-stylsheet', because those don't seem to be doing anythinng at all when I switch the theme. Also, only the stylesheets and scripts are getting switched, and not the theme template files (index, header, footer..etc).. Why might this be happening?

Comment: @NickRes this is work only if you are past inside simple plugin. In functions.php add_filter template not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `switch_theme()` method. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme