# How to Get Different Themes on Different WordPress Pages?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to install different wordpress themes for different pages. How do I do it?

I am trying to get a different theme for my about-me page.

Need some guidance on going about doing it.

Comment: [This is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24766911/1287812) but very problematic

Answer (score 0):

For styling a specific page you can use:

```
page-{slug}.php
```

so in your case create a file in your template root directory

```
page-about-me.php
```

and if you use wordpress `body_tag()` you can style it with

```
body.about-me{
    //your rules
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare a file in your theme folder xyz.php, then just make it a template of wordpress and provide it a template name. Put your css in style.css file and just include this template to About-me page through admin panel. All the code you have put in your template will only work for About-me page.

You can do the same process for other pages you want to show them with a different layout. Just get some idea from here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates