# Changed wordpress template by url Parameter

Tags: wordpress

Where wordpress determinds the template which is loaded? Ich want to changed the template Depended on a url Parameter. Also a hacky solution is welcomed

Comment: wordpress determine the theme using values stored in the database. And what you want to do is to break the wordpress logic which not a good idea as you will end up with a buggy thing

Comment: what you may do is to create a button that allow you to change the theme (update the database) and then refresh the site

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code, so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need following: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100858 , [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772581/3475869](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100858)

But you need to do more detailed research before ask.